# How to select subset of 3D numpy array ending in a value?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, subset

I have a 3D numpy array looks like this

```
shape(3,1000,100)

[[[2,3,0,2,6,...,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],
[1,4,6,1,4,5,3,...,1,2,6,-1,-1],
[7,4,6,3,1,0,1,...,2,0,8,-1,-1],
...
[8,7,6,4,...,2,4,5,2,1,-1]],
...,
[1,5,6,7,...,0,0,0,0,1]]]
```

Each lane of array end with 0 or multiple(less than 70 I'm sure) **-1**.

For now, I want to select only 30 values before the **-1** for each lane, to make a subset of original numpy array with shape of `(3,1000,30)`

Should be similar like this,

```
[[[...,0],
    [...,1,2,6],
    [...,2,0,8],
    ...
    [...,2,4,5,2,1]],
    ...,
    [...,0,0,0,0,1]]]
```

Is it possible to do it with some numpy functions? Hope without a for loop:)

Comment: Are there -1 elements elsewhere on the line ? And yes it is possible. Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Hi,@MadPhysicist It is the third dimension with the length of 100. '-1' only at the end of each line. Not in the middle or start. I searched some of the documents it shows how to use indexing. Like you can use  array[3,1000,70:100].  But here each has different numbers of '-1'. I don't know where to start to select this subset.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one making use of [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
def preceedingN(a, N):
    # mask of value (minus 1 here) to be found
    mask = a==-1

    # Get the first index with the value along the last axis.
    # In case its not found, choose the last index  
    idx = np.where(mask.any(-1), mask.argmax(-1), mask.shape[-1])

    # Get N ranged indices along the last axis
    ind = idx[...,None] + np.arange(-N,0)

    # Finally advanced-index and get the ranged indexed elements as the o/p
    m,n,r = a.shape
    return a[np.arange(m)[:,None,None], np.arange(n)[:,None], ind]
```

Sample run -

Setup for reproducible input :

```
import numpy as np

# Setup sample input array
np.random.seed(0)
m,n,r = 2,4,10
a = np.random.randint(11,99,(m,n,r))

# Select N elements off each row
N = 3

idx = np.random.randint(N,a.shape[-1]-1,(m,n))
a[idx[...,None] < np.arange(a.shape[-1])] = -1
a[0,0] = range(r) # set first row of first 2D slice to range (no -1s there)
```

Input, output :

```
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [81, 23, 69, 76, 50, 98, 57, -1, -1, -1],
        [88, 83, 20, 31, 91, 80, 90, 58, -1, -1],
        [60, 40, 30, 30, 25, 50, 43, 76, -1, -1]],

       [[43, 42, 85, 34, 46, 86, 66, 39, -1, -1],
        [11, 47, 64, 16, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
        [42, 12, 76, 52, 68, 46, 22, 57, -1, -1],
        [25, 64, 23, 53, 95, 86, 79, -1, -1, -1]]])

>>> preceedingN(a, N=3)
array([[[ 7,  8,  9],
        [50, 98, 57],
        [80, 90, 58],
        [50, 43, 76]],

       [[86, 66, 39],
        [47, 64, 16],
        [46, 22, 57],
        [95, 86, 79]]])
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a solution based on the idea of calculating the indices which should be kept. We use `numpy.argmin` and `numpy.nonzero` to find the start of the `-1` or the end of the row, then use 2-dimensional addition/subtraction to build the indices of the 30 elements that need to be kept.

First off, we create reproducible example data

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(3, 1000, 100))
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(1000):
        a[i, j, np.random.randint(low=30, high=a.shape[2]+1):] = -1
```

You can of course skip this step, I just added it to allow others to reproduce this solution. :)

Now let's go through the code step-by-step:

1. Change shape of a to simplify code

   ```
   a.shape = 3 * 1000, 100
   ```
2. Find index of -1 in each row of a

   ```
   i = np.argmin(a, axis=1)
   ```
3. Replace any indices for rows of a with no -1 by a 100

   ```
    i[np.nonzero(a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), i] != -1)] = a.shape[1]
   ```
4. Translate indices to 1D

   ```
   i = i + a.shape[1] * np.arange(a.shape[0])
   ```
5. Calculate indices for all elements that should be kept. We make the indices two-dimensional so that we get the 30 indices before each -1 index.

   ```
   i = i.reshape(a.shape[0], 1) - 30 + np.arange(30).reshape(1, 30)
   a.shape = 3 * 1000 * 100
   ```
6. Perform filtering

   ```
   a = a[i]
   ```
7. Return a to desired shape

   ```
   a.shape = 3, 1000, 30
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Here's one using `stride_tricks` for efficient retrieval of slices:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

# create mock data
data = np.random.randint(0, 9, (3, 1000, 100))
fstmone = np.random.randint(30, 101, (3, 1000))
data[np.arange(100) >= fstmone[..., None]] = -1

# count -1s (ok, this is a bit wasteful compared to @Divakar's)
aux = np.where(data[..., 30:] == -1, 1, -100)
nmones = np.maximum(np.max(np.cumsum(aux[..., ::-1], axis=-1), axis=-1), 0)

# slice (but this I'd expect to be faster)
sliceable = as_strided(data, data.shape[:2] + (71, 30),
                       data.strides + data.strides[2:])
result = sliceable[np.arange(3)[:, None], np.arange(1000)[None, :], 70-nmones, :]
```

Benchmarks, best solution is a hybrid of @Divakar's and mine, @Florian Rhiem's is also quite fast:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

# create mock data
data = np.random.randint(0, 9, (3, 1000, 100))
fstmone = np.random.randint(30, 101, (3, 1000))
data[np.arange(100) >= fstmone[..., None]] = -1


def pp(data, N):
    # count -1s
    aux = np.where(data[..., N:] == -1, 1, -data.shape[-1])
    nmones = np.maximum(np.max(np.cumsum(aux[..., ::-1], axis=-1), axis=-1), 0)

    # slice
    sliceable = as_strided(data, data.shape[:2] + (data.shape[-1]-N+1, N),
                           data.strides + data.strides[2:])
    return sliceable[np.arange(data.shape[0])[:, None],
                     np.arange(data.shape[1])[None, :], 
                     data.shape[-1]-N-nmones, :]

def Divakar(data, N):
    # mask of value (minus 1 here) to be found
    mask = data==-1

    # Get the first index with the value along the last axis.
    # In case its not found, choose the last index  
    idx = np.where(mask.any(-1), mask.argmax(-1), mask.shape[-1])

    # Get N ranged indices along the last axis
    ind = idx[...,None] + np.arange(-N,0)

    # Finally advanced-index and get the ranged indexed elements as the o/p
    m,n,r = data.shape
    return data[np.arange(m)[:,None,None], np.arange(n)[:,None], ind]

def combined(data, N):
    # mix best of Divakar's and mine
    mask = data==-1
    idx = np.where(mask.any(-1), mask.argmax(-1), mask.shape[-1])
    sliceable = as_strided(data, data.shape[:2] + (data.shape[-1]-N+1, N),
                           data.strides + data.strides[2:])
    return sliceable[np.arange(data.shape[0])[:, None],
                     np.arange(data.shape[1])[None, :], 
                     idx-N, :]


def fr(data, N):
    data = data.reshape(-1, data.shape[-1])
    i = np.argmin(data, axis=1)
    i[np.nonzero(data[np.arange(data.shape[0]), i] != -1)] = data.shape[1]
    i = i + data.shape[1] * np.arange(data.shape[0])
    i = i.reshape(data.shape[0], 1) - N + np.arange(N).reshape(1, N)
    data.shape = -1,
    res = data[i]
    res.shape = 3, 1000, 30
    return res

print(np.all(combined(data, 30) == Divakar(data, 30)))
print(np.all(combined(data, 30) == pp(data, 30)))
print(np.all(combined(data, 30) == fr(data, 30)))

from timeit import timeit

for func in pp, Divakar, combined, fr:
    print(timeit('f(data, 30)', number=100, globals={'f':func, 'data':data}))
```

Sample output:

```
True
True
True
0.2767702739802189
0.13680238201050088
0.060565065999981016
0.0795100320247002
```

Comment: Creating the windows upfront and indexing thereafter was some thinking!